# rclcpp - float conversion warning when using `declare_parameter<float>`

Tags: ros2, c++, parameters, rclcpp

Compiling a node with the following snippet and `-Wfloat-conversion` leads to the following:

```
component.cpp:24:56: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘float’ may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]
24 |   float linear_acceleration_stddev = declare_parameter<float>("linear_acceleration_stddev", 1e-3f);
```

even if:

1. I used `float` as template param
2. I assigned as default value a `float` literal
3. I am assigning to a `float` variable

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Honestly, it looks to me like you're doing everything correct... there might be a conversion happening under-the-hood with the declare_parameter implementation, where they're going from the float you provide to a double, and then you convert that double to a float. If that's what's happening you may be out of luck, you might just have to stick with doubles or accept this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All floating point Parameters end up being doubles under the hood - so your "declare_parameter" is basically being recast as "declare_parameter" - and then the implicit conversion from double to float generates the warning.

My suggestion would be to explicitly do the cast - which should get rid of the warning:

> float linear_acceleration_stddev = static_cast<double>(declare_parameter("linear_acceleration_stddev", 1e-3));

As a side note - rclcpp will NOT do this automatic recasting the it is a vector (for instance, you can have a vector<double> parameter type - but vector<float> won't even compile). This very fun limitation is the sole reason I had once dug deep enough into rclcpp to be able to answer your question...